# Jquery child element on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying, using jquery, to trigger an event when a child element, in this case select, changes.

**Here is my HTML**:

```
<div id="addForm" ng-repeat="forme in formes" class="row addForm">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <select id="geo_{{forme.id}}" ng-model="forme.geo" class="form-control">
            <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
            <option value="triangle">Triangle rectangle</option>
            <option value="cercle">cercle</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The javaScript** that is not working yet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.body).on("change", "#addForm > select", function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.body).on("change", ".addForm > select", function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

Both method are not working

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not working because, `addForm` is a `class` not an `id`.

```
$(document).on("change", ".addForm select", function () {
   alert(this.value);    
});
```

use `.classSelector` instead of an `#id` selector.

Also I missed out pointing another one error. That is, `select` is not a direct child of `.addForm` it is a descendant. Use `descendant selector` instead of a `child selecor`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qqqatLmz/)

Comment: The class is there cuse i was testing the classSelector as well. Both of them are not working. The only way i got it working is by passing the id of the select element manually to jquery which is not good for me since they are object being added using angularjs

Comment: @MadeInDreams Can you check the demo and my answer now?

Comment: Yes this is working. Thank you. Can you tell me why the : or the > needed to be removed in this case? And it is working with the id selector to.

Comment: @MadeInDreams `>` will select the direct children elements, whereas `the space` (the descendant selector) will select the descendant elements that includes direct children also.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!