# Blazor problem with updating bootstrap tooltip

Tags: blazor

So, how can I use the bootstrap tooltip with Blazor?
I tried to use it like this:

**MainLayout.razor:**

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setTooltip");
}
```

**setTooltip:**

```js
function setTooltip() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

It's fine when the content is updated on MainLayout, but if the child component has been updated, it does obviously nothing.

How i can dynamically update a tooltip with no other code in childs?

Comment: Since you are on the javascript side, the onchange event of document might help you out here, have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35966779/3936440

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`HxTooltip`](https://havit.blazor.eu/components/HxTooltip) or take a look at [`HxTooltip`'s source-code](https://github.com/havit/Havit.Blazor/blob/master/Havit.Blazor.Components.Web.Bootstrap/Tooltips/HxTooltip.cs) where this is covered.